# $(modalEl).modal('show') and $(modalEl).modal('hide') not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using bootstrap-modal from :

https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal

modalEl is the modal element in DOM.
Modal is completely rendered in the with some dynamic content.

I want to hide the modal, do some work on application and would like to render that same modal later again without initialising the any new modal.

How do i do that???

I have removed `data-dismiss="modal"` attribute from the button.

but the following not working in my case

```
$(modalEl).modal('hide');

$(modalEl).modal('show');
```

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? What steps have you taken to debug the problem?

Comment: sorry i was using default approach of twitter bootstrap while using bootstrap-modal.js from different vender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'bootstrap-modal.js' provided from https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal is at least little different if compared from the default modal provided from twitter bootstrap.

for the modal root div (here taken as modalEl)

to show hide default twitter bootstrap we use :

```
    $(modalEl).modal(); // initialize
    $(modalEl).modal('hide'); // hide
    $(modalEl).modal('show'); //show
```

However if we use modal from https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal we should use the following way :

```
var modalObj = $(modalEl).modal(); // initialize
modalObj.modal('hide') // to hide
modalObj.modal('show') // show
```